# What does this piece of Perl code do in laymans terms?

Tags: perl

Found this inside a loop. I've read up about splice but it just confused me more.
I'm not familiar with Perl, but am trying to translate an algorithm to another language.

```
my $sill = splice(@list,int(rand(@list)),1);
       last unless ($sill);
```

To be more specific: What will be inside $sill if it doesn't exit the loop from the last?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This randomly removes one element from the array `@list`. That value is assigned to `$sill`. If that was a false value, the enclosing loop (not shown) is broken out of.

[`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) takes an array, an offset, and a length, plus a replacement list. If the replacement is omitted, the elements are deleted.

The length is constant (1 element), but the offset is calculated as a random integer smaller between 0 and the length of `@list`.

Comment: so $sill has the value of the removed item? Kinda like how a stack works, but it pops at a random location?

Comment: @user2054454 yes, exactly. (In fact, the data structure works as a “(doubly) linked list”)

Answer (score 2):

That means :

- remove a random element from the array `list` (0 -> numbers of element of the list) and
- assign the `sill` variable with the removed element (`pop()` like) and
- exit the loop if `sill` variable is false

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html

Comment: Minor correction on your last bullet point: It exits the loop if `$sill` is false, not if it's void. Aside from `undef` (void), the number 0, the string '0', and the empty string are also false and would cause the loop to exit. To exit only when `$sill` is void/`undef`, you would use `last unless defined $sill`.